# Problems adding JS OnClientClick to a button in code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I am trying to add buttons programmatically to a page and when they are clicked I want to call a function in the parent (the buttons are in a jQuery dialog) the function works fine because I have been using it another way too but I am having problems adding the JS to the onClientClick from the code-behind.

```
btnLink.OnClientClick = "window.parent.openlink(http://www.google.co.uk, test, 300, 300);return false;";
```

I have looked in developer tools and it isnt setting the onclientclick but instead using onclick, I don't know if this causes a problem.

This is an example of a button on the parent page and how it is generated (working model):

```
<input name="btnOpen" class="DataControlButtons" id="btnOpen" onclick="openlink('CustomerTypes-Open.aspx', 'Open', '1000', '470'); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnOpen&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" type="submit" value="Open">
```

This is how the non-working button is generated:

```
<input name="ctl02" onclick="window.parent.openlink(http://www.google.co.uk, test, 300, 300);return false;" type="submit" value="Configuration">
```

Comment: It's ok, `OnClientClick` in ASP.NET exists just because `OnClick` is already occupied by the server-side event. In browser it should be `onclick`. What is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt do anything when I click the button, not even an error.

Comment: At first, if you are in the jQuery dialog - you are essentially in the same window, not in a browser popup window. So `parent` should be removed. Also `openlink` is not clear, browsers support only `open` for popups.

Comment: I am using window.parent in the same page on another button that's not programmatic and it works. The openlink is a custom function followed by parameters)

Comment: Also it is in fact another window, the dialog loads another page inside it called PageSubMenu.aspx.

Comment: At least it should be provided with string parameters I suppose. Try wrapping `http://www.google.co.uk` and `test` parts with quotes

Comment: I just posted examples of how the working and non working buttons are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function string parameters lack quotes, making this call an invalid javascript. Try turning them into valid strings:

```
btnLink.OnClientClick =
    "window.parent.openlink('http://www.google.co.uk', 'test', 300, 300);return false;";
```

Comment: If you thought my question was valid, would you mind up voting it for me, thanks again.